# Python: What happens when I modify imported class?

Tags: python

I have written the following code to modify the behavior of a method of one class

```
import mymodule
mymodule.MyClass.f = mydecorator(mymodule.MyClass.f)
mymodule.MyClass.f(x) # call the modified function
```

This works for my purposes, but: what have I modified exactly? Is `mymodule.MyClass` a copy of the original class living inside the current module? Does it in any way affect the original class? How does import work exactly?

Comment: Say, you declare `x = 5` in some file... now, another program imports `x` and changes it to 10. What happens?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I'm not exactly sure

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens. The original is not modified. All you are importing is a copy into your namespace.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify imported module, you modify the cached instance. Thus your changes will affect all other modules, which import the modified module.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache

**UPDATE:**

You can test it.

change_sys.py:

```
import sys

# Let's change a module
sys.t = 3
```

main.py:

```
# the order of imported modules doesn't meter
# they both use cached sys
import sys
import change_sys

print(sys.t)
```

Output for `python ./main.py`:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. In normal uses cases everything should be ok. But one can imagine special cases where it can lead to weird results:

a.py:

```
import c

x = c.C()

def disp():
    return x.foo()
```

b.py:

```
import c

def change():
    c.C.foo = (lambda self: "bar at " + str(self))
```

c.py:

```
class C:
    def foo(self):
        return "foo at " + str(self)
```

Now in top level script (or interactive interpretor) I write:

```
import a
import b
a.disp()
b.change()
a.disp()
```

Output will be:

```
'foo at <c.C object at 0x0000013E4A65D080>'
'bar at <c.C object at 0x0000013E4A65D080>'
```

It may be what you want, but the change has been done in `b` module and it does affect `a` module.